# How to receive data from server using PHP socket

Tags: php

I am having a hard time getting data from the server. Basically server waits for a connection from anyone using correct username and password. So when I use that using local explorer it shows the data on the browser.
[image]

Now what I was trying to do is, get this data using socket and forward it to another server address. But I could not even connect to the server to get the data like I get on the browser. Here is what I have tried:

```
$host = "192.168.1.4/online?user=dneb&pass=mella88";
$port = 1850;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "server Message : ".$input;
```

When I run this code I get warning message:

> Warning: socket_bind(): Host lookup failed [11004]: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\socket\client.php on line 10
>   Could not bind to socket

Or suggest other methods to use.

Comment: If you need to do a HTTP request then use the right tools for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a socket server, you don't specify the host as the full URL to your script; that's why the bind is failing.

Take a look at this sample: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

please try changing

```
$host = "192.168.1.4";
```

Comment: but the server will not respond without the username and password.